# Accessing an array that is in a list that is a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have a big nested dictionary that holds some timeseries data, my goal is to extract that timeseries data. I am able to do some basic dictionary navigating, but all of these different datatypes within each other is really throwing me off. Here's an MWE with a nested dictionary that holds datetime data and precipitation data from 2 different monitoring sites. Eventually, I would like to plot them together with any number of monitoring sites.

Here I do my best to get the data from the dictionary into a numpy array, then into a pandas dataframe. You'll see, though, that the dataframe has one row per station and one column that holds each station's precip array. I expected it to show the same number of columns that there are data values. Is this the best way to reach my goal? If so, how do I change the number of columns?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

no_stations = 2
my_dict = {
    "UNITS":{
        "precipitation":"Inches"
        },
        "STATION": [
            {'STATUS': 'ACTIVE',
             'NAME' : 'STATION 1',
             'ELEVATION': '758',
             'OBSERVATIONS': {'date_time': [
                '2020-04-13T13:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T14:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T15:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-13T16:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T17:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T18:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-13T19:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T20:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T21:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-13T22:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T23:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T00:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T01:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T02:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T03:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T04:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T05:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T06:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T07:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T08:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T09:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T10:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T11:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T12:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T13:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T14:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T15:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T16:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T17:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T18:00:00Z'],
            'precip_accum_set_1': [
                 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.254, 1.27, 2.794, 4.064, 5.588, 6.858, 8.89, 10.922,
                 12.192, 12.954, 13.716, 15.24, 18.034, 18.288, 18.288, 18.288, 20.32,
                 22.606, 24.892, 25.908, 26.924, 27.432, 27.686, 27.686,
                 27.686, 27.686, 27.94]}},
            {'STATUS': 'ACTIVE',
             'NAME' : 'STATION 2',
             'ELEVATION': '500',
             'OBSERVATIONS': {'date_time': [
                '2020-04-13T13:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T14:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T15:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-13T16:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T17:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T18:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-13T19:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T20:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T21:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-13T22:00:00Z', '2020-04-13T23:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T00:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T01:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T02:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T03:00:00Z',
                 '2020-04-14T04:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T05:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T06:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T07:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T08:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T09:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T10:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T11:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T12:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T13:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T14:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T15:00:00Z',
                '2020-04-14T16:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T17:00:00Z', '2020-04-14T18:00:00Z'],
            'precip_accum_set_1': [
                49.53, 49.53, 49.53, 50.038, 51.054, 52.324,53.594, 54.864, 56.134,
                59.944, 61.214, 61.722,62.484, 64.008, 66.802, 67.056, 67.056, 67.31,
                69.088, 71.628, 74.168, 75.184, 75.946, 76.454,76.708,
                76.708, 76.708, 76.708, 76.708]}}
                ]
            }


for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(key)
    print(type(value))

precip = np.empty([no_stations], dtype=object)
dates = np.empty([no_stations], dtype=object)

for ii in range(no_stations):
    precip[ii] = my_dict['STATION'][ii]['OBSERVATIONS']['precip_accum_set_1']
    dates[ii] = my_dict['STATION'][ii]['OBSERVATIONS']['date_time']
    precip[ii] = np.array(precip[ii], dtype = float)
    dates[ii] = np.array(dates[ii], dtype = str)

df = pd.DataFrame(precip)
print(df)
```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the station-specific data is inside of of `my_dict['STATION']`, which contains a dictionary for each station, each of which has an `'OBSERVATIONS'` key.  The value in the dictionary under this key has the timeseries values, contained under two keys, `date_time` and `precip_accum_set_1`.

To get the data into a dataframe, we want to access this `'OBSERVATIONS'` key for each station.  You can do this with a list comprehension.  This list contains two dictionaries (one for each station), each with two keys `date_time` observations and `precip_accum_set_1`

```py
my_list = [station['OBSERVATIONS'] for station in my_dict['STATION']]
```

To get each of these to a dataframe, you can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`:

```py
list_df = [pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).set_index('date_time') for d in my_list]
```

If you want to create a single dataframe with both stations, use `pd.concat` and use the station names from `my_dict['STATION']` as `keys`:

```py
my_df = pd.concat(list_df, keys=[station['NAME'] for station in my_dict['STATION']], names=['NAME'])
```

```py
my_df.head()
                                    precip_accum_set_1
NAME        date_time   
STATION 1   2020-04-13T13:00:00Z    0.000
            2020-04-13T14:00:00Z    0.000
            2020-04-13T15:00:00Z    0.000
            2020-04-13T16:00:00Z    0.254
            2020-04-13T17:00:00Z    1.270


my_df.tail()
                                    precip_accum_set_1
NAME        date_time   
STATION 2   2020-04-14T14:00:00Z    76.708
            2020-04-14T15:00:00Z    76.708
            2020-04-14T16:00:00Z    76.708
            2020-04-14T17:00:00Z    76.708
            2020-04-14T18:00:00Z    NaN
```

Based on your needs, you can transform it as needed:

1. Transpose the data with `my_df.T` to get 60 columns (one row with a column for each station/time combination)
2. Return one row per station and one column per time with `my_df.unstack()`
3. Pivot the data to have one row per time and one column per station with `my_df.reset_index(level='NAME').pivot(columns='NAME', values='precip_accum_set_1')`
4. Convert the index from string to datetime with `pd.to_datetime`

***Note:*** Your example dictionary has a mismatched number of `date_time` (30) and `precip_accum_set_1` (29) observations for `STATION 2`, which will need to be addressed to make the example work.  I added an additional `np.nan` to make the example work, but you should check that the actual data isn't causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code with output a dataframe with the same number of columns as data values, let me know if I have misunderstood what format of dataframe you were aiming for:

```
# code as in your question


precip = [my_dict['STATION'][ii]['OBSERVATIONS']['precip_accum_set_1'] for ii in range(no_stations)]
dates = [my_dict['STATION'][ii]['OBSERVATIONS']['date_time'] for ii in range(no_stations)]

precip_df = pd.DataFrame(precip)
print(precip_df)

dates_df = pd.DataFrame(dates)
print(dates_df)
```

Output:

```
precip_df:
      0      1      2       3       4   ...      25      26      27      28     29
0   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.254   1.270  ...  27.686  27.686  27.686  27.686  27.94
1  49.53  49.53  49.53  50.038  51.054  ...  76.708  76.708  76.708  76.708    NaN

[2 rows x 30 columns]

dates_df:
                      0  ...                    29
0  2020-04-13T13:00:00Z  ...  2020-04-14T18:00:00Z
1  2020-04-13T13:00:00Z  ...  2020-04-14T18:00:00Z

[2 rows x 30 columns]
```